# Adding a CSS class to razor @Html.DisplayFor

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to set a new class for this part of my code, but it doesn't work correctly

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.melk.Code, new { @class = "myClass" } )
```

Can anyone tell me where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406482%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) that you are using will find the DisplayTemplate based on the type of the `model.melk.Code` and the last parameter (anonymous object `new { @class = "myClass" }` will be passed to the template's ViewData. You have to use that ViewData in the corresponding template in order for it to work.

```
<div class="@(ViewData["class"])"...
```

Answer (score 10):

Boris showed you the correct overload, but there is also the dead simple way to just change it to:

```
<span class="myClass">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.melk.Code)
</span>
```

Personally, I find it simpler, so easier to remember and maintain, even if it's not so framework-specific.