# Apply a colored box around my Status field

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application which uses Bootstrap v2.0.4, and i use the following to display the value for a status field:-

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AssetState.DISPLAYSTATE, new { @class= Model.AssetState.DISPLAYSTATE.ToString() } )
```

Then i added the following inside my css file:-

```
.operational {

color:green;
}
.Disposed {
    color:red;
}
```

But the above did not have any effect on the produced markup and the displayed value will always return the default color ?

Comment: Is the class being applied to the element? What I mean is when you inspect HTML do you see the class name on the element?

Comment: Can you include your AssetState.DISPLAYSTATE object declaration? It appears that when the razor view is compiled the class value is not available at the time. Its hard to know without seeing the actual model declaration. However to test you can try something like @{ var classvalue = Model.AssetState.DISPLAYSTATE.ToString() ?? "operational"; } then assign to the HTML helper @class = classvalue

Comment: @anpsmn no using the F12 tool the class name will not be shown..

Comment: @Bosman the result for applying your code is as follow:- <span>In Use</span>

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18685512/473016) may help in adding class to the element

Comment: not sure if the link is correct, as according to the DisplayFor template it accept a @class parameter ..

Comment: `Html.DisplayFor()` does not have an overload that accepts html attributes (only `additionalViewData`). You can create you own `DisplayTemplate` and pass the class name as `additionalViewData` and use it to set the class (see the link provided by @anpsmn)

Answer (score 0):

Do like following it'll work,

```
<span class="@Model.AssetState.DISPLAYSTATE.ToString()">   
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AssetState.DISPLAYSTATE )
</span>
```

Reference:
[Adding a CSS class to razor @Html.DisplayFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685432/adding-a-css-class-to-razor-html-displayfor)

[how to apply CSS for @Html.DisplayFor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962127/how-to-apply-css-for-html-displayfor)

If you want to do differently, which is not provided by the html helper, then follow the instruction from the link. You can write your own html helper.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/720515/Custom-HTML-Helper-for-MVC-Application

Comment: no the Displaystate is not enu, because if i write the following directly inside the view "Model.AssetState.DISPLAYSTATE" , then Razor view will show the actual state , the Model object passed to the view is a single object..

Comment: Ok i tried the following "<span> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AssetState.DISPLAYSTATE, new { @class="testval23"})</span>". but the class will not be applied to the produced text ,, seems the problem is inside the DisplayFor template which is not accepting @class parameters...

Comment: Hi, Refer the following links. You'll get. DisplayFor is not having html attribute as paramter.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962127/how-to-apply-css-for-html-displayfor
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962127/how-to-apply-css-for-html-displayfor

Comment: So you should do like following,
<span class="testval23"> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AssetState.DISPLAYSTATE)</span>

Comment: why i think i should be able to pass the class directly to the Displayfor ??? why this is not working ?

Comment: Html Helper provide this as default functionality.. if you want, you can customize your html helper. Try the following link, it'll help you..
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/720515/Custom-HTML-Helper-for-MVC-Application..
Updated in answer